# Prove that any rational number is positive $\frac{m}{n}$ Can be displayed in the form of a "continued fraction"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continued-fractions

> "Continued fraction" is an expression of the form
>
> $[a_{0},a_{1},a_{2}...,a_{n}]=
> > a_{0}+\frac{1}{a_{1}+\frac{1}{a_{2}+\frac{1}{a_{3}+_{\frac{1}{...+}}}}}$
>
> $a_{0},a_{1},a_{2}...,a_{n}$ are natural numbers. Example:
> $\frac{275}{52}=[5,3,2,7]= 5+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{7}}}$
>
> **Prove that any rational number is positive $\frac{m}{n}$ Can be displayed in the form of a "continued fraction" (induction for n)**

I think for proving with induction start with base (n=1), we get [1]= 1+1=2

then assuming $[a_{0},a_{1},a_{2}...,a_{n}]$ is a rational number, then we need to prove that $[a_{0},a_{1},a_{2}...,a_{n},a_{n+1}]$ is rational

But I don't know how to continue from here

Comment: Looks more like a *continued fraction expansion* to me.

Comment: See for example: [The Wikipedia page on Continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Motivation_and_notation)

Comment: What if $m < n$. How do you do $\frac 1{17}$ as such?

Comment: What about the number $1$.  If $1 = m + \frac 1{k}$ then $m=0\not \in mathbb N$.

Comment: @fleablood Usually if the rational number $r$ is an integer its continued fraction just stops at the initial $a_0.$ [I see you may be objecting to the OP's write-up which seems to imply the CF is not just a single integer but has at least one $1/b$ part/]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof by induction that any positive rational number $\frac{m}{n}$ can be written as a finite continued fraction (i.e., a continued fraction $[a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_N]$ with a finite number of entries). The induction is on the numerator $n$.

If $n=1$, the proposition is true: $\frac{m}{1}=m=[m]$.

Let's now assume that for all $k$ such that $1\leq k\leq n$ it is possible to represent a positive rational number $\frac{m}{k}$ as a finite continued fraction. Then the same is true if $1\leq k\leq n+1$. Indeed, $\frac{m}{n+1}=a+\frac{r}{n+1}$, where $0\leq r\le n$. If $r=0$, we are done
($\frac{m}{n+1}=a=[a]$). If $r>0$, then
$\frac{r}{n+1}=1/\frac{n+1}{r}$; since $r\leq n$, the denominator of the latter fraction can be represented as a finite continued fraction, i.e., $\frac{n+1}{r}=[b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_q]$, so that $\frac{m}{n+1}=a+1/[b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_q]=[a,b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_q]$. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

It's an algorithm, extended Euclidean Algorithm done, deliberately, in the terminology of continued fractions.

$$ \frac{ 275 }{ 52 } = 5 +  \frac{ 15 }{ 52 } $$
$$ \frac{ 52 }{ 15 } = 3 +  \frac{ 7 }{ 15 } $$
$$ \frac{ 15 }{ 7 } = 2 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 } $$
$$ \frac{ 7 }{ 1 } = 7 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 & & 5 & & 3 & & 2 & & 7 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 5 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 16 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 37 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 275 }{ 52 }  
 \end{array}
 $$

and we can read off
$$  $$
$$ 275 \cdot 7 - 52 \cdot 37 = 1 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ \frac{ 479 }{ 231 } = 2 +  \frac{ 17 }{ 231 } $$
$$ \frac{ 231 }{ 17 } = 13 +  \frac{ 10 }{ 17 } $$
$$ \frac{ 17 }{ 10 } = 1 +  \frac{ 7 }{ 10 } $$
$$ \frac{ 10 }{ 7 } = 1 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 7 } $$
$$ \frac{ 7 }{ 3 } = 2 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 } $$
$$ \frac{ 3 }{ 1 } = 3 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
 & & 2 & & 13 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 27 }{ 13 }   & &   \frac{ 29 }{ 14 }   & &   \frac{ 56 }{ 27 }   & &   \frac{ 141 }{ 68 }   & &   \frac{ 479 }{ 231 }  
 \end{array}
 $$
$$  $$

so that we get Bezout (little 2 by 2 determinant):
$$ 479 \cdot 68 - 231 \cdot 141 = 1 $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$